# Pagination not displaying PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to paginate my query only nothing is being outputted, can anybody see where im going wrong? Im very new to PHP/PDO

```
else {
try
    {
    $per_page = '3';
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != ''");
    $rows = $result ->fetchAll();
    $total_records = count($rows);
    $pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page); 
    $page  = (isset ($_GET['page']))  ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ;
    $start = ($page - 1) *  $per_page; 
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != ''");
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<br>' . $row['id'] . '<br>' . $row['First_Name'] . '<br>' . $row['Surname'] . '<br>';
    } ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php
    if ($pages >=  1 && $page <= $pages){
    //if ($page>1 && $page <= $pages){$previous=($page -1); echo '<a href="?page=' .$previous. '">Previous</a>';}
    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){ echo ($x == $page) ? ' <strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : ' <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';}
    //if ($page>1  && $page <= $pages){ $next=($page+1) ; echo '<a href="?page=' .$next. '">Next</a>';}
    }
    ####################### Close Database #######################
    $db = NULL;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
    } 
};
```

Comment: I don't see any sort of pagination logic in your SQL queries. (i.e. LIMIT) so that might be something you need to look at.  Besides that, can you provide information on what errors you are getting? Or where in your script things are going wrong based on your debugging efforts? Also, why make the same exact query twice?

Comment: Pagination is usually done using `LIMIT`. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html for LIMIT. The number of records is usually retrieve by using `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You never [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the query.

```
$result->execute();
$rows = $result ->fetchAll();

$query->execute();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: This causes my page to not display @musa

Answer (score 1):

Also it's better to use `LIMIT` in your query. Something like that:

```
//to get need page
$per_page = 3;
$page  = (isset ($_GET['page']))  ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ;
$result = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM directory 
     WHERE user_active != '' 
     LIMIT ".(($page - 1) *  $per_page).", ".$per_page
);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result ->fetchAll();

//to get count of pages
$result = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM directory 
     WHERE user_active != ''"
);
$result->execute();
$total-pages = reset($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM));
```

Comment: This doesnt output anything to the browse unfortunately @Tyranron